# std::is_member_function_pointer does not compile if false

Tags: c++, type-traits, if-constexpr

**What I am looking for:** I have a templated class and want to call a function if the class has the wanted function, something like:

```
template<class T> do_something() {
    if constexpr (std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::x)>::value) {
        this->_t->x(); // _t is type of T*
    }
}
```

**What happens:** The compiler does not compile if `T` does not bring the function. Small example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    void x() { }
};

class Bar { };

int main() {
    std::cout << "Foo = " << std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&Foo::x)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bar = " << std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&Bar::x)>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler says:

```
is_member_function_pointer.cpp:17:69: error: no member named 'x' in 'Bar'; did you mean 'Foo::x'?
    std::cout << "Bar = " << std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&Bar::x)>::value << std::endl;
```

So, what is the `std::is_member_function_pointer` for, when I can not use it in an `if constexpr`? If I just use `this->_t->x()` the compiler will fail, too, for sure.

Comment: you don't check if the type is a function pointer, you try to see a function pointer which did not exist

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But how can I check that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`is_member_function_pointer` doesn't detect the existence of an entity `T::x`, it assumes it does and returns whether or not it is a member function pointer.

If you want to detect whether it exists or not, you can use the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected). Example:

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template<class T>
using has_x = decltype(&T::x);

template<class T> void do_something(T t) {
    if constexpr (std::experimental::is_detected<has_x, T>::value) {
        t.x(); 
    }
}

struct Foo {
    void x() { }
};

struct Bar { };

int main() {
    do_something(Foo{});
    do_something(Bar{});
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/DLCWFF)

---

I have written an article on the general problem of checking the validity of an expression in different C++ Standard versions:

[**"checking expression validity in-place with C++17"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/checking_expression_validity_in_place.html)